# Regular expression for length and replace

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match the below mentioned conditions

I need to do this using only 1 REGEX which can cater all the conditions , any help please

i want to change the BTN into german format like this

```
from : 004171511326 to->494171511326  (BTN starts with '00' and length of BTN is 12)

from : 01777203102  to->491777203102  (BTN starts with '0' and length of BTN is 11)

from : 1772576210   to->491772576210  (Length of BTN is 10)

from : 015732888810 to->491573288881  (BTN starts with '0' and length of BTN is 12 )
```

Comment: Any attempts yet? Also, why did the last BTN lose the last 0?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and explain what worked and what didn't work.  Chances are you'll come close, and we'll have something to go off of.

Comment: This post sounds dangerously like you're just asking people to do your (home)work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of head scratching I finally managed to come up with this solution:

```
(?(^\d{12}$)(?(^0[1-9])0?(?<digit>.{10})|\d*(?<digit>.{10}))|\d*(?<digit>.{10}))
```

which does the exact same thing as SQL query + giving result in Group[1] all the time so I didn't have to change the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Two regex's. Probably shouldn't be further factored.

---

Uses branch reset -

Find:  `\b(?|00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b`
Replace:  `49$1`

```
 \b 
 (?|
      00 
      ( \d{10} )         # (1)
   |  
      0 
      ( \d{10} )         # (1)
      \d? 
   |  
      ( \d{10} )         # (1)
 )
 \b
```

Uses cluster group -

Find:  `\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b`
Replace:  `49$1$2$3`

```
 \b 
 (?:
      00 
      ( \d{10} )         # (1)
   |  
      0 
      ( \d{10} )         # (2)
      \d? 
   |  
      ( \d{10} )         # (3)
 )
 \b
```

Output >>

```
 from : 004171511326      to-> 494171511326
 from : 01777203102       to-> 491777203102
 from : 1772576210        to-> 491772576210
 from : 015732888810      to-> 491573288881
```

Dot-Net C# test case

```
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("004171511326", @"\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b", @"49$1$2$3"));
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("01777203102",  @"\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b", @"49$1$2$3"));
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("1772576210",   @"\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b", @"49$1$2$3"));
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("015732888810", @"\b(?:00(\d{10})|0(\d{10})\d?|(\d{10}))\b", @"49$1$2$3"));
```

Output >>

```
 494171511326
 491777203102
 491772576210
 491573288881
```

Comment: hi thanks . i m using .net and getting "Unrecognized grouping construct" while using branch reset , using cluster group giving me result in separate groups but how to use replace as U have mentioned ?

Comment: I am not able to understand this syntax "49$1$2$3" , can you please elaborate

Comment: @Danyal - Dot-Net doesn't support branch reset, use the other regex. The replacement `"49$1$2$3"` is a catenation of "49"+<captur group 1 variable>+<captur group 2 variable>+<captur group 3 variable>. Only one group will contain content at each match, the others will be blank. We don't worry about which one, the catenation will be correct. Somehow you have to join these in the replacement string.

Comment: Added a C# test case.

Comment: Thanks very much sln . that really helped in getting the understanding and came to know about these 2 new features of cluster group and branch reset . Thankfully at least one is supported in .net